# how a dns query works

Tags: domain-name-system

when i type www.google.com how does the dns lookup work. According to my knowledge it first goes to the root server and finds out where the .com dns server is. Next it returns the ip address of that server. Next from there is finds out where the google server is. Now it returns a ip address and that would be the place where www.google.com is found.

So to resolve this two dns look ups are needed. Correct me if iam wrong.

Comment: First, the DNS server that your computer has statically configured or received via DHCP is asked. This server might be able to answer your query directly, because it is authoritative for the name you asked for or because it has cached the answer. Only if not, other DNS servers and finally a root server is used. But in principle (without any caching) you are right.

Comment: what do you mean by finally a root server is used ? I thought the first lookup goes to a root server ?

Comment: Your admin can install copies of zones, which are periodically updated, on your server to provide clients with faster answers. Obviously, not the whole internet can be stored, so which servers are used depends on whether there is a copy or not. Are you interested in what really happens (that can be very complicated) or what happens in principle?

Answer (score 6):

DNS resolution can get pretty hairy when you start to consider things like caching and anycast, but let's keep it simple for now.

Here are snippets of digs next to snippets of tcpdumps of a query for www.google.com to a freshly started nameserver, so no caching is being used.  I've trimmed some of the timestamps for legibility.

First, the local nameserver (here 192.168.10.10) asks one of the root servers (in this case h.root-servers.net, 128.63.2.53) the query "what is the A record for www.google.com?"  h.root-servers.net is not authoritative for www.google.com, but it does have a delegation for .com, so it returns that.

```
192.168.10.10.17203 > 128.63.2.53.53: 29969 [1au] A? www.google.com. (43)
128.63.2.53.53 > 192.168.10.10.17203: 29969- 0/15/16 (719)

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.                        IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
com.                    172800  IN      NS      a.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      b.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      c.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      d.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      e.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      f.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      g.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      h.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      i.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      j.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      k.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      l.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      m.gtld-servers.net.
```

Second, the local nameserver then chooses one of the nameservers from the list returned by h.root-servers.net and sends the same query: "what is the A record for www.google.com?"  In this case the nameserver queried was f.gtld-servers.net (192.35.51.30).  f.gtld-servers.net, which is authoritative for .com, has responded with the nameserver delegations for the zone google.com

```
192.168.10.10.65182 > 192.35.51.30.53: 58632 [1au] A? www.google.com. (43)
192.35.51.30.53 > 192.168.10.10.65182: 58632- 0/4/5 (179)

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.                        IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
```

Getting closer!  Now the local nameserver picks one of the nameservers in the last response and asks it the same question.  In this case, it asks ns2.google.com (216.239.34.10).  ns2.google.com responds that www.google.com is actually a CNAME (canonical name) record for www.l.google.com

```
192.168.10.10.4767 > 216.239.34.10.53: 15830 [1au] A? www.google.com. (43)
216.239.34.10.53 > 192.168.10.10.4767: 15830*- 6/0/0 CNAME[|domain]

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.         604800  IN      CNAME   www.l.google.com.
```

Very close!  Now we just need the address of www.l.google.com.  Now because we already know the nameservers for google.com, we just ask one of them.  In this case, we ask ns3.google.com (216.239.36.10) "what is the A record for www.l.google.com.?"  It responds with the address, and we have our answer:

```
192.168.10.10.63657 > 216.239.36.10.53: 62511 [1au] A? www.l.google.com. (45)
216.239.36.10.53 > 192.168.10.10.63657: 62511*- 5/0/0 A[|domain]

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.l.google.com.              IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.l.google.com.       300     IN      A       74.125.232.116
www.l.google.com.       300     IN      A       74.125.232.112
www.l.google.com.       300     IN      A       74.125.232.115
www.l.google.com.       300     IN      A       74.125.232.113
www.l.google.com.       300     IN      A       74.125.232.114
```

Huzzah!

Anyway, I hope that's enough to get your started. There are a lot of great resources out there.  The O'Reilly book "DNS and BIND" is very useful.

I highly highly highly recommend installing dig to use for seeing how the DNS queries go.  For example, you can use dig +trace to easily see the delegation path to a host:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.0-P1 <<>> +trace www.google.com
;; global options: +cmd
.                       516930  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       516930  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       516930  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       516930  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       516930  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       516930  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       516930  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       516930  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       516930  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       516930  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       516930  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       516930  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       516930  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
;; Received 244 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) in 1 ms

com.                    172800  IN      NS      i.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      j.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      c.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      l.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      d.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      h.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      a.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      e.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      b.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      g.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      f.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      k.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      m.gtld-servers.net.
;; Received 492 bytes from 202.12.27.33#53(m.root-servers.net) in 45 ms

google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
;; Received 168 bytes from 192.33.14.30#53(b.gtld-servers.net) in 42 ms

www.google.com.         604800  IN      CNAME   www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com.       300     IN      A       74.125.232.115
www.l.google.com.       300     IN      A       74.125.232.113
www.l.google.com.       300     IN      A       74.125.232.116
www.l.google.com.       300     IN      A       74.125.232.114
www.l.google.com.       300     IN      A       74.125.232.112
;; Received 132 bytes from 216.239.34.10#53(ns2.google.com) in 131 ms
```

Notice how similar it is to the trace of the query earlier?
Hope that helps.

Comment: I think its worth mentioning that a recursive nameserver knows the IP addresses of the nameservers for the root zone - they are called root nameservers - from either its configuration (root.hints file) or they are compiled in its source.

Answer (score 4):

It is slightly more complicated as DNS is quite heavily cached. Your local machine may even have the data cached and the lookup goes no further than that.

Your machine will query it's own cache and if that fails it will query the primary DNS server it has been told about. This may be a caching DNS server and my have the result in it's cache in which case the record is returned to you and the lookup ends. It is also most likely a recursive DNS server and will now do the leg work for your machine.

If the primary DNS server doesn't have the information it will query the root name servers they will respond with (in your example) the TLD name servers for .com

A query will be sent to the .com TLD servers which will respond with the address of the authoritative name server for google.com

A query will be sent to the authoritative name server for google.com requesting the www.google.com record. This will be found and returned to the primary DNS server which will cache it and return the record to you.

Answer (score 3):

DNS is hierarchical and, as lain said, heavily cached. Perhaps, a more complicated example can help you.

Assume you have a machine that belongs to a company with several business units which are reflected in the domain structure. Your machine has the name machine.businessunit1.company.com, i. e. belongs to businessunit1.company.com, which is your primary DNS suffix.

The business unit is very large and operates several DNS servers (dns1.businessunit1.company.com, dns2.businessunit1.company.com) and also e. g. a webserver called www.businessunit1.company.com.

If your machine now wants to resolve www.businessunit1.company.com, it will first lookup the local DNS cache. I. e. your machine itself remembers DNS entries you recently queried, because it is very likely that you will need the results again, e. g. when you click a link on a website. I do not know whether you can see what your machine has cached, but there is a command for deleting everything your machine remembered (on Windows): `ipconfig /flushdns`

If your machine does not remember the answer, it will ask - as I previously commented - the DNS server(s) that are configured for your network adapter. Most likely, your admins will have configured dns1.businessunit1.company.com and dns2.businessunit.company.com. The reason for that is that you want your DNS query answered quickly without a lot of traffic. If dns1.businessunit1.company.com receives your query for www, it will answer it, because it is authoritative for the zone *.businessunit1.company.com. Authoritative means that this server knows the only correct answer for all DNS names ending "businessunit1.company.com".

Now assume you have queries www.businessunit2.company.com. Your machine, if it does not rememember the answer itself, will again ask dns1.businessunit1.company.com. Now, there are a lot of possibilities: first, your admins might be clever, and they have forseen that it is very likely that people from businessunit1 will also want to access machines in businessunit2 frequently. Therefore, they have configured dns1.businessunit1.company.com to hold a copy of the data from dns1.businessunit2.company.com. dns1.businessunit1.company.com can use this copy to answer your question. Second, your admins will surely have told dns1.businessunit1.company.com what to do when it does not know the answer to your question: that is asking another DNS server. Probably, this is dns1.company.com, but it could also be any other DNS server, including the root servers.

As lain said, dns1.businessunit1.company.com is free to remember any answer it got from other DNS servers. I. e. if you ask for www.google.com, it might have to ask some other server, but if you ask a second time, it remembers the answer and tells you directly.

You can basically see where your DNS answer is from when you type e. g. `nslookup www.google.com`. The output will tell you the server and whether it is an authoritative answer or not. Most likely, it will be non-authoritative, because it is not answered by Google's DNS servers, which are responsible for all DNS names ending "google.com".

Comment: You can display the local DNS cache using `ipconfig /displaydns`

Answer (score 1):

In fact, everything is very complicated and depends on the DNS server. Unbound make [66 query](http://pastebin.com/cjD89mi0).

Answer (score 0):

You're not wrong. [Here's a great illustration of how a DNS query works.](http://www.nominet.org.uk/digitalAssets/45012_dns-query.gif)

Comment: that host in the middle of the diagram called the resolver? Is it really a seperate host ? I thought that the resolver was the pc that needs the ip address of the url.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. And maybe 1 more look up for the "www" subdomain.

Comment: there may be millions of urls that has the www portion. How can you get a unique ip if you lookup www ?

Comment: The DNS hierarchy goes from back to front. If you just type www, the DNS search list of your machine will be used to complete the name.