# Do foreign domains, like .ly take longer to resolve?

Tags: domain, resolve

I have a .ly domain I want to get - but my concern is that initial resolution will take longer then a simple .com domain (e.g. when a customer views my site). Or is it just duplicated on domestic name servers, and doesn't matter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How a DNS query works](http://serverfault.com/questions/227259/how-a-dns-query-works)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They may initially depending on the DNS look-up sources. The more obscure or less popular domains may not be cached with the same frequency as the more popular ones. All subsequent lookups afterwards should be the same performance as any other cached lookup.

Answer (score -3):

What country do you think `.com` belongs to?   Think carefully before you answer.  Bonus question: Who is the `.us` domain for?

Comment: It's for us, of course! (The absence of `.you`, `.him` and `.her` puzzles .me, though ;))

Comment: @Piskvor: No, no, it's `.us` versus `.them`, of course.